# Is there a way to hide an HTML5 video immediately after it's played?

Tags: html, video, hide, playback

I'm working on a website and the client really insists on having a video with sound that plays once the video is clicked.

The problem is that the video needs to disappear immediately after it's played.

Is this even possible?

I was trying some jQuery and JS but no success.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to provide a specific use case and show your attempt.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow, Unfortunately this question does not include enough details for us to help reproduce the problem. Please do not ask us to do something for you without showing any efforts or any code attempts. Visit the how to ask section of stackoverflow for more tips about how to ask a good question and what questions are suitable for the site

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can hide the video after playing. Here's what I would do.

- Get the video object
- Add a listener to the video to listen to when it finishes (`ended`)
- Set the display style to `none`

Here's my code:

Javascript:

```js
function setupVideo () {
// get video
  var video = document.getElementById('myVideo')
  // Play the video, this is optional
  video.play();
  // Add a listener to this video, so that when the video ends, the video is "hidden".
  video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  // hide video
    video.style.display = "none";
  })
}
```

HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="your_js_file.js" type="text/javascript" />
<!-- Other content -->
  </head>
  
  <body onload="setupVideo()">
    <video controls src="your_video.mp4" id="myVideo">
      Video not supported
    </video>
  </body>
<!-- Other content -->

</html>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/thunderredstar/7w3hrqbo/1/
(Please make sure to run the fiddle)